# How to plot Numerical Values in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have this kind of database:

```
     Time Type  Profit
2      82  s/l   -51.3
5       9  t/p  164.32
8      38  s/l  -53.19
11     82  s/l   -54.4
14    107  s/l  -54.53
..    ...  ...     ...
730   111  s/l  -70.72

731   111  s/l  -70.72
732   111  s/l  -70.72
733   113  s/l  -65.13
734   113  s/l  -65.13

[239 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to plot a chart which shows X as the time (that's already on week hours), and Y as profit(Which can be positive or negative). For Y, I would like for each hour (X) to have 2 bars to show the profit. The negative profit would be positive too in this case but in another bar.

For example we have -65 and 70. They would show as 65 and 70 on the chart but the loss would have a different bar color.

This is my code so far:

```
#reading the csv file
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Time','Type','Profit']).astype(str)

#turns time column into hours of week
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: findHourOfWeek(x))

#Takes in winning trades (t/p) and losing trades(s/l)
df = df[(df['Type'] == 't/p') | (df['Type'] == 's/l')]



#Plots the chart
ax = df.plot(title='Profits and Losses (Hour Of Week)',kind='bar')
#ax.legend(['Losses', 'Winners'])
plt.xlabel('Hour of Week')
plt.ylabel('Amount Of Profit/Loss')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens when you have two negative values like in `731, 732`?

Comment: They need to add up. For ex. instead of 70.72, it needs to be 212.16 (adding up all the profit/loss during the hour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby, unstack and plot:

```
(df.groupby(['Time','Type']).Profit.sum().abs()
   .unstack('Type')
   .plot.bar()
)
```

For your sample data above, the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thank You. If we have profit and loss on the same day, does it show as 2 bars under the same X element?

Comment: Yes, notice how the blues are on the left and the oranges on the right of the ticks. try it on your data.

Comment: Thanks this definitely fixed it. If you don't mind, can you explain what unstack and groupby do?

Comment: Groupby().sum() sums the values by type and day. Unstack turns type into columns. And pandas allows grouped bar charts by columns.